# Closing faded div doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I've got such a code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){    

$('.cod').click(function() {
var div_name = $(this).attr('id');

$('.overlay_window').load('/templates/' + div_name + '_template.php', function(){
   var div_width = $('#'+div_name+'-overlay').width();
   var div_height = $('#'+div_name+'-overlay').height();
    $('.overlay_window').css("width", ""+div_width+"px")
    $('.overlay_window').css("height", ""+div_height+"px")
    var div2_width = $('.overlay_window').width();
    var div2_height = $('.overlay_window').height();
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    var window_height = $(window).height();

    var widthoffset = (window_width - div2_width) / 2;  
    var heightoffset = (window_height - div2_height) / 2;   
    $('.overlay_window').css("left", "" + (widthoffset) + "px");
    $('.overlay_window').css("top", "" + (heightoffset) + "px");
    $('.overlay_background').fadeIn();
    $('.overlay_window').fadeIn();
  });
});

$('#zamknij').click(function() {
  return false;
  $('.overlay_background').hide();
  $('.overlay_window').hide();
});


});
```

and HTML

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<div id="invite-overlay" style="width:400px; height:200px; ">
Zaproś swojego znajomego do grona <b>Levelowiczów</b>!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="zamknij" style="color:#aaaaaa; font-family:Bebas; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;">X Zamknij</a><br /><br />
Już teraz możesz zaprosić znajomego, aby zarejestrował się z twojego <b>Ref Linku</b>, dzięki czemu uzyskasz punkty, które wymienia się na nagrody w konkursach.<br /><br />
<b>Oto twój link:</b><br />

<input style="width:400px; height:25px; border:none; background:#ffffff; border-top:1px solid #e2e2e2; border-left:1px solid #e2e2e2;" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo("http://xxx/register.php?ref_link=" .  $_SESSION['uniq_key'] . ""); ?>">
</div>
```

and i want to hide all this while clicking X Zamknij

```
$('.overlay_background').hide();
$('.overlay_window').hide();
```

this part is in index.php file and is hidden. it is container for the window that appears on center of window

EDIT

The part with divs of overlay

```
<body>
<div class="overlay_background"></div>
<div class="overlay_window"></div>
```

Comment: Where is .overlay_window in your HTML?

Comment: in index.php right after <body> tag

Comment: You didn't show that part in your question. Could you post that part too?

Comment: check the question edited it and thats on bottom of it

Comment: See my answer, I've put a link up with a live working JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing `return false;` in your function, it stops the execution of the function, hence your `return false;` needs to be at the end of the function like so:

```
$('#zamknij').click(function() {
  $('.overlay_background').hide();
  $('.overlay_window').hide();
  return false;
});
```

You should get the click handler binding call for #zamknij out of your click, like I have on the JSFiddle.

See this JSFiddle for a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/A6UZ9/2/

Comment: Only JS. When you have problems like this, check out your developer console in Chrome. Might have some errors there that can help you debug. Press F12 to access it.

Comment: Wow, you're about as unclear as it gets eh? We do need more information than it doesn't work.

Comment: but its all neccesary info that script uses

Comment: $('#zamknij').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $('.overlay_background').hide();
 $('.overlay_window').hide();
}); and nothing so idk wat to do

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the `return false;` statement to the bottom of the click handler for `#zamknij`? The code under it can't run.

Answer (score 0):

#### Move the `return false` to the end:

```
$('#zamknij').click(function() {
  $('.overlay_background').hide();
  $('.overlay_window').hide();
  return false;
});
```